# Multiple (bulk) upload with the media browser widget

Tags: 7, media, files

I'm using [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) 7.x-2.0, and I would like to be able to upload more than one image/media at the same time with the media browser widget. How can I do this?

I know about [Plupload](https://drupal.org/project/plupload) but I just need HTML5 support and don't want a special widget.

There is also [Multiupload Filefield Widget](https://drupal.org/project/multiupload_filefield_widget), but I want to keep the media browser widget.

Comment: For uploading more than one image you need to follow these steps:

1. Go to Configeration -> Content -> Wysiwyg ->profile -> choose from either filtered HTML or Full HTML or Plain text that you want to configure ->  EDIT -> Click on Buttons and Plugins option and in that put check on **MEDIA BROWSER** and save the configuration.
2. Now go to the ADD content and in the CCK Editor you will have an option for **Media Browser** 
3. Click on Media Browser option multiple times and upload as many images that you want to upload.

Comment: @NiteshSethia gagarine meant bulk upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use https://drupal.org/sandbox/fangel/1652676 to be able to upload multiple images and still be able to access the media library.

Comment: Is it only option still? Isn't there any other way for today?

Comment: I believe the media module issue to follow is https://www.drupal.org/node/951004.  That would replace the module https://drupal.org/sandbox/fangel/1652676.

I also read that https://www.drupal.org/project/dragndrop_upload works at https://www.drupal.org/node/2237779#comment-10344479

Comment: The problem is that `media_multiupload` doesn't work with the newest Media module version. It causes `Fatal error: Call to undefined function media_attach_browser_js() in modules/media_multiselect/media_multiselect.module on line 117`.