# Media Module Bulk File Upload

Tags: media

Is there a way to bulk upload into the Media module? What I'm trying to do is get a huge batch of images into the media Library browser. It seems like you have to first establish the image as an entity in the D7, so most of these bulk methods using something like rsync of scp wont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Plupload integration](https://drupal.org/project/plupload) module allows you to upload multiple files at once.

I've used this module before and I think it works really well. It also allows you to drag and drop files onto the browser window to initiate the upload.

[image: Plupload uploading multiple files]

Comment: But how does this integrate with the Media module? And further: can you map the directory you are uploading to, or does it just drop everything into sites/default/files?

Comment: Yes, it integrates with the media module and you can set where files are uploaded too.

Comment: @FelixEve how does it integrate with the media modal window? Can give some direction for this?

Comment: It does't integrate with the media modal window :( But is there on the `/file/add` form. [This answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75372/multiple-bulk-upload-with-the-media-browser-widget) helped me set it up.

Comment: @FelixEve ok, thanks. I would like to see it integrated in the media modal window. I see it somewhere but don't remember where...